# How to create a record array by querying a stream in ballerina?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a stream of results coming from the github client as below.

```
stream<github:Repository, github:Error?> repositories = check githubEp->getRepositories("google", true);
```

And I have a defined record type named Repository as below.

```
type Repository record {|
    string repoName;
    int? stargazerCount;
|};
```

How do I create an array of Repository records by querying the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow two approaches here. You can use either query expressions or query actions. You can use it depending on the use case.

1. Query Expressions - If your requirement is create a new array by filtering a stream.

```
Repository[] repoArray = check from github:Repository repo in repositories
        select {repoName: repo.name, stargazerCount: repo.stargazerCount};
```

2. Query Actions - If you already have an array defined and you need to add the values coming from stream to that array.

```
Repository[] repoArray = [];
check from github:Repository repo in repositories
    do {
        repoArray.push({
            repoName: repo.name,
            stargazerCount: repo.stargazerCount
        });
    };
```